# ticks not appearing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm graphing some data and want tick marks on the x-axis of my plot. My data looks like:

```
  publication   labels   percentage
1 foo           0       .4572
2 foo           1       .0341
3 foo           2       .09478
4 foo           3       .0135
5 bar           0       .7442
6 bar           1       .2847
```

in which each name has labels from 0 to 9.

My code looks like:

```
ggplot(aes(y = percentage, x = labels, color = publication), data = labelsdf)+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                   labels = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'))
```

But my graph looks like:

[image]

There weren't any tick marks without the `breaks` or `labels` specified either. Why aren't my ticks appearing?

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without showing us what the data look like. A possibility is that all your actual data fall in between two specified tick marks.

Comment: @snapcrack Which version of `ggplot2` are you using??

Comment: @Prradep 2.2.1.9000. And to Remko, I added some data; I didn't think to add it because it has straightforward discrete values but hopefully this helps.

Comment: `publication` column or vector is not present

Comment: i renamed it to "name" accidentally and changed it back.

Comment: you should also change `label` to `labels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After explicitly mentioning the `labels` as discrete using `scale_x_discrete`, you need to make them as discrete using `factor()` otherwise the values will still be numeric.

```
ggplot(aes(y = percentage, x = factor(labels), color = publication), data = df)+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                   labels = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'))
```

[image]

After using, you may wish to change the Axes labels as per your requirement.

---

As the `labels` is already discrete, it is not required to use `scale_x_discrete` with `breaks`.

```
ggplot(aes(y = percentage, x = labels, color = publication), data = df)+
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

If you want the x-axis labels differently (i.e., start with `1` instead of `0`) from what present in the dataframe, you can get that using the small tweak as:

```
ggplot(aes(y = percentage, x = labels+1, color = publication), data = df)+
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Factor works. I should also add that I figured out using "scale_x_continuous" works as well without factoring the variable. The problem with not applying "scale_x_discrete" was that I ended up with useless ticks like 2.5, 5. 7.5, etc.